# After upgrading my SpringBoot application from 2.7 to to 3.1 a JPA Repository stored procedure call fails to be prepared, why?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So we have there a stored procedure in our Informix database:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE cp_cno_LinkToTrans(ai_notice_id    INTEGER,
                                    avc_txn_type    VARCHAR(3),
                                    ai_txn_id       INTEGER);
```

This procedure has no output parameters or returned rows or value.

In our application we have used a Spring Data JPA repository method that is annotated with `@Procedure("cp_cno_LinkToTrans")`, that has three input parameters, does not return anything.

And this method was successfully called like that under SpringBoot 2.7 and it's Hibernate 5.6 and other dependencies.

Now after upgrading, we get

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement [A syntax error has occurred.] [{call cp_cno_LinkToTrans(:id,:type,:transId)}]; SQL [{call cp_cno_LinkToTrans(:id,:type,:transId)}]`

This fails before even calling the procedure, The engine is preparing a statement to be executed.

Has something changed in the way to define stored procedures in Spring Data? Is there a bug?

Comment: any solution? I am also getting error while calling jakarta NamedStoredProcedureQuery